# Python: Any clue as to what i should do next? attached is the assignment my code

Tags: python

**The homework question is:**
When you (or your parents) rip songs from a cd, the digital file is created by sampling the sound at some rate. Common rates are 128kbps (128 x 2^10 bits per second), 192, 256. Write a function "def songs(capacity, bitrate) " that returns the number of 4 minute songs someone can fit on his or her ipod. The function's two parameters are the capacity of the ipod in gigabytes (GB) and the sampling rate in kbps. A gigabyte is 2^30 bytes and a byte contains 8 bits. Also write a complete program (with a main function) that gets these two values using the I"Input" function, passes them to your songs function, then prints the number of songs.

***BELOW IS MY CODE***
I feel like i'm missing half of the things I need to complete the function but I am not sure how to code them. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am using python 3.6

```
"""Chapter 3 assignment
Purpose: To complete the tasks assigned in the chapter 3 assignments folder
Author: Dominic Gigli
Date Created 15 Feb 2018
"""

def main():
    def songs(capacity, bitrate):
        """The point of this program is to find out how many 4 minute songs can fit on an ipod. It will multiply capacity and bitrate and take the users storage size input and the out
        put will display how many songs fit. parameters will be capacity, bitrate"""

    # capacity: The size of the device in question
    #  bitrate: The sampling rate in kbps
    #  Length of songs: The time of the songs are 4 minutes
    # return: the number of songs that can be stored\

    capacity = int(input('enter the size of the storage on the ipod: '))
    bitrate = int(input('enter the rate of transfer (common rates are 128, 192, 256 kbps):'))
    answer = capacity * bitrate
    print('The number of songs that can fit are', answer)


main()
```

Comment: Convert the gigabytes in `capacity` to kilobits, calculate the necessary number of kilobits for a 4 minutes song from `bitrate` and divide.

Comment: Only show the relevant parts of code. Remove all the comments at the top, including your name